# Golang pgx: Update with RETURNING statement returns error when Scanning row

Tags: go, postgis, pgx

I use Postgres with the Postgis extension and [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) & [sqlf](https://github.com/leporo/sqlf) on the Go side.
Inserting/deleting and reading Rows works fine I'm just struggeling with Updates of a row since I always get this error returned from `pgx` when I try to scan the returned row into a Go struct.

```
no rows in result set
```

Below is the method I created to do partial updates. I first creates the SQL query and set columns to update and also add a `RETURNING` statement to return the whole row. Since my location column is a Postgis Point I need to wrap the column with the `ST_AsBinary` function so that I can scan it into an [Orb.Point](https://github.com/paulmach/orb).

```golang
type UpdatePartyParams struct {
    ID            string
    Title         string
    Lat           float32
    Long          float32
    StreetAddress string
    PostalCode    string
    State         string
    Country       string
    StartDate     time.Time
    EndDate       time.Time
}

func (d Directory) UpdateParty(ctx context.Context, arg UpdatePartyParams) (Party, error) {
    sqlf.SetDialect(sqlf.PostgreSQL)
    b := sqlf.Update(TABLE_NAME)

    if arg.Title != "" {
        b = b.Set("title", arg.Title)
    }
    if arg.Lat != 0 && arg.Long != 0 {
        b = b.SetExpr("location", "ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326)", arg.Long, arg.Lat)
    }
    if arg.StreetAddress != "" {
        b = b.Set("street_address", arg.StreetAddress)
    }
    if arg.PostalCode != "" {
        b = b.Set("postal_code", arg.PostalCode)
    }
    if arg.State != "" {
        b = b.Set("state", arg.State)
    }
    if arg.Country != "" {
        b = b.Set("country", arg.Country)
    }
    startYear := arg.StartDate.Year()
    if !(startYear == 1970) {
        b = b.Set("start_date", arg.StartDate)
    }
    endYear := arg.StartDate.Year()
    if !(endYear == 1970) {
        b = b.Set("end_date", arg.EndDate)
    }

    b.
        Where("id = ?", arg.ID).
        Returning("id, user_id, title, is_public, ST_AsBinary(location) AS location, street_address, postal_code, state, country, start_date, end_date")

    log.Println(b.String()) // UPDATE parties SET title=$1 WHERE id = $2 RETURNING id, user_id, title, is_public, ST_AsBinary(location) AS location, street_address, postal_code, state, country, start_date, end_date

    row := d.pool.QueryRow(ctx, b.String(), b.Args()...)
    var i Party
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.ID,
        &i.UserID,
        &i.Title,
        &i.IsPublic,
        wkb.Scanner(&i.Location),
        &i.StreetAddress,
        &i.PostalCode,
        &i.State,
        &i.Country,
        &i.StartDate,
        &i.EndDate,
    )

    return i, err
}
```

My Database Schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE parties (
    id varchar(27) PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_public BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    location geometry(POINT, 4326) NOT NULL,
    street_address TEXT,
    postal_code TEXT,
    state TEXT,
    country TEXT,
    start_date TIMESTAMP,
    end_date TIMESTAMP
);
```

The mentioned error is caused by the [row.Scan](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx#Row.Scan) method and thrown *"If no rows were found"*. But when I execute the sql statement with a difference SQL UI client it works fine and the row is returned. Any Idea what could cause the `row.Scan()` method to fail and the row not to be returned?

### Edit

The weird part is that a simple read for one row works fine and scans the returned record into the Go struct. Below is a working method which uses the same `row.Scan` method just through a `select` statement.

```golang
func (d PartyRepository) GetParty(ctx context.Context, id string) (Party, error) {
    sqlf.SetDialect(sqlf.PostgreSQL)
    b := sqlf.
        Select("id, user_id, title, is_public, ST_AsBinary(location) AS location, street_address, postal_code, state, country, start_date, end_date").
        From(TABLE_NAME).
        Where("id = ?", id)

    log.Println(b.String())

    row := d.pool.QueryRow(ctx, b.String(), b.Args()...)
    var i Party
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.ID,
        &i.UserID,
        &i.Title,
        &i.IsPublic,
        wkb.Scanner(&i.Location),
        &i.StreetAddress,
        &i.PostalCode,
        &i.State,
        &i.Country,
        &i.StartDate,
        &i.EndDate,
    )
    return i, err
}
```